# Can an android phone pause wifi scan requests?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I wrote an android application to request a scan for available wifi signals around, using the WifiManager, then dump the results to a file. The program works fine, but this weird bug occurs.

Initially I was requesting a scan every 30 seconds, and everything worked fine. I then tried to request a scan every two seconds, I get this strange bug. Everything will work fine for a few minutes, then the time between two scan requests jumps from 2 seconds to 50 seconds for no reason. Then, for four more scans, it will scan at 2-second intervals, then skip to a 50-second interval, and it continues to do this consistently.

With larger time intervals this bug does not appear. Has anyone experienced this bug before? Is there a way to prevent it? Or does Android automatically cancel scan requests if they are too frequent?

Thank you for your help!

NS

Comment: Without knowing the exact API, I agree with steve.  You are probably being blocked because a request like this every two seconds could be detrimental to the battery, normal wifi operations, etc.  Have you tried raising it a bit at a time to find the threshold where it will work without problems?

Comment: Any chance WifiManager runs in a thread?

Comment: this is similar to the question asked on google group.  http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3c34ebe1819976cb

Comment: Serotonin - Yes, it runs in a thread, would that do something?
Vinay - Haha that's my coworker :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance of posting some code?

Could this be an intentional limitation placed upon developers to avoid killing the battery.

Comment: It was a limitation, but they removed it. Thanks!